# Ruby SVG '<': comparison of String with 0 failed (ArgumentError)'

Tags: ruby, svggraph

I'm trying to write a svg graph using a pgsql connection. I'm having an issue with writing the data to a svg. I've used the documentation from the svggraph for a timeseries graph.

```
    require 'svggraph'


graph = SVG::Graph::TimeSeries.new(
{
  :width => 640,
  :height => 480,
  :graph_title => "Tweets per Day",
  :show_graph_title => true,
  :no_css => true,
  :key => true,
  :scale_x_integers => true,
  :scale_y_integers => true,
  :min_x_value => 0,
  :min_y_value => 0,
  :show_data_labels => true,
  :show_x_guidelines => true,
  :show_x_title => true,
  :x_title => "Time",
  :show_y_title => true,
  :y_title => "Tweets",
  :y_title_text_direction => :bt,
  :stagger_x_labels => true,
  :x_label_format => "%y-%m-%d",
})



graph.add_data({
  :data => data1,
  :title => 'Test'})


File.open('timeseriesgraph.svg','w'){File.write(graph.burn)}
```

Currently it's writing a blank document. (I checked it in notepad++).

Here is the error string.

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/svg-graph-2.0.1/lib/SVG/Graph/Plot.rb:250:in `<': comparison of String with 0 failed (ArgumentError)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/svg-graph-2.0.1/lib/SVG/Graph/Plot.rb:250:in `min_y_range'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/svg-graph-2.0.1/lib/SVG/Graph/Plot.rb:256:in `y_range'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/svg-graph-2.0.1/lib/SVG/Graph/Plot.rb:272:in `get_y_values'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/svg-graph-2.0.1/lib/SVG/Graph/Graph.rb:410:in `calculate_left_margin'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/svg-graph-2.0.1/lib/SVG/Graph/Plot.rb:181:in `calculate_left_margin'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/svg-graph-2.0.1/lib/SVG/Graph/Graph.rb:951:in `calculate_graph_dimensions'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/svg-graph-2.0.1/lib/SVG/Graph/Graph.rb:203:in `burn'
    from tweet_graph.rb:49:in `block in <main>'
    from tweet_graph.rb:49:in `open'
    from tweet_graph.rb:49:in `<main>
```

Comment: Gonna guess that `data1` contains strings not numeric values. Can you verify the contents of `data1` ?

Comment: Hey, It should be an ordered pair of [date,count,date,count] for plotting.